# How to maintain the data at XML document after changing schema with Diagramer?

Tags: data, esri-geodatabase, xml, loading, arcgis-diagrammer

After exporting XML with schema and data I did some changes to the schema with ArcGIS [Diagramer](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5af1723bab4e413bae63dd89daa87984). now i need to import the new schema and all the data to a new empty file GDB. what are the best practices for this ?
 using "Publish" on diagramer save only the schema. How can i load the data most efficiently (i have more the 40 layers) from XML to geodatabase ?